# Why do these CSS animations go away after clicking on the page?

Tags: css, animation, blueprintjs

#### Description of behavior

In the following gif, when the subtitles (gray text) are loaded they still seem to have the same background animations as the loading state i.e. the `background-color` is still animating. After I click, the animations go away and the subtitles render as expected (no `background-color` animations). This only happens in Chrome. I couldn't reproduce this in Safari.

[image: CSS animations and clicking]

#### Details

The general dom structure for one of the boxes in the above gif looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="title modifier">...</div>
  <div class="subtitle modifier">...</div>
</div>
```

Depending on the loading state, the `modifier` placeholder above is either `pt-skeleton` (a CSS class that carries some of these animation styles) or none. The code for the styles is [here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/core/src/components/skeleton/_skeleton.scss#L64).

When inspecting the subtitles while they're showing both glowing background *and* text, nothing in the styles indicates that there's an `animation` property being set. Why does Chrome decide to temporarily keep the CSS styles from a class that's no longer being applied to my element?

[possibly relevant Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666710&q=os%3Amac%20component%3ABlink%3EAnimation%20&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: Did you mean to prefix the `modifier` class name with a period?

Comment: oops typo on my end. editing the question

Comment: It would be helpful to paste the relevant code into a snippet in your question so we can see the problem first-hand.

Comment: Sounds like CSS is cached to your browser.  ------Why does Chrome decide to temporarily keep the CSS styles from a class that's no longer being applied to my element?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the cache (ctrl+f5)?

Comment: @chazsolo i've linked you to the animation styles code. that class is effectively toggled on/of depending on my loading state.

Comment: @jmag i don't think caching is the problem because even though i'm displaying a loading state, i've already pulled in all the stylesheets that i need by that point.